# It's ok to ask the question about Travis CI?

Tags: discussion, tags

It's ok to ask the question about testing build with [Travis CI](http://www.travis-ci.org/)?
If yes, can we have tag for [travis-ci](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci)?

Answer (score 1):

Wow I'm a little late to the party. That no one showed up for. Yikes.

Yes, absolutely that's welcome. There's dozens of questions about Jenkins, and it seems Travis is similar.

I've created a [travis-ci](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci) tag and put it on an existing question about Travis. Note that the tag will be deleted if a new Travis question isn't posted in 6 months (that's just how it works to keep non-used tags from filling up the system...)